# Prestashop: PDF invoice uses a different font depending on the language (French vs. English)

Tags: pdf, fonts, prestashop-1.5, invoices

Using Prestashop 1.5.5.0 for a bilingual store (English/French), I noticed that the PDF generated for the invoice had a noticeably different presentation depending if it was generated in English or in French.

The most noticeable differences are:

- the font family used is different in English: the letters are sensibly larger (esp. in lower case), and of different shapes; I was not able to identify which font it is, however.
- in English, every text element that is supposed to be bold appears with a normal font-weight (not bold, then); my guess is that the font-family that is used in English doesn't have a bold variant.

Here's a comparison of both fonts (French left, English right):

[image: font comparison]

Just to be sure, I made a very small change to the `invoice.tpl` file (I just added a simple dot somewhere in the content), and then I re-downloaded the PDF invoice in both languages: the change appeared in both languages. So both languages use the same TPL file. Yet they do not use the same font-family.

My question is: where should I look in order to correct that?
I can't find any font-family declaration in the TPL files, and I don't understand why English would use a different font-family than French.

**Edit:** By the way, if somebody is able to identify (with reasonable certainty) which font is used in English (see image above), please let me know in the comments, as I may be able to use that information to search through all the files of the site and maybe get an idea where this problem comes from?...

Comment: It would be best to post examples of each PDF file, its much more likely that we can tell you which font is used from the PDF than from looking at screen shots.

Also, what application are you using to view the PDF files ?

Comment: I'm reluctant to post a PDF file as it may contain sensitive information (it's not my site). Anyway, I just discovered that you can display the list of used fonts through Acrobat, via the File > Properties menu item (Fonts tab). This has indeed allowed me to solve the issue (I'll post my answer right away), although it's still kind of a hack...

Answer (score 3):

So, I [just discovered](https://superuser.com/a/140750/91490) that you can get a list of the fonts used in the PDF document through Acrobat itself (menu File > Properties, Fonts tab).

This has allowed me to identify the font used in the English invoices PDF: **DejaVuSans**. I ran a search on this term across all the files of the site, and I found my culprit in `classes/pdf/PDFGenerator.php`, which has this variable defined:

```
public $font_by_lang = array(
    'ja' => 'cid0jp',
    'bg' => 'freeserif',
    'ru' => 'freeserif',
    'uk' => 'freeserif',
    'mk' => 'freeserif',
    'el' => 'freeserif',
    'en' => 'dejavusans',
    'vn' => 'dejavusans',
    'pl' => 'dejavusans',
    'ar' => 'dejavusans',
    'fa' => 'dejavusans',
    'ur' => 'dejavusans',
    'az' => 'dejavusans',
    'ca' => 'dejavusans',
    'gl' => 'dejavusans',
    'hr' => 'dejavusans',
    'sr' => 'dejavusans',
    'si' => 'dejavusans',
    'cs' => 'dejavusans',
    'sk' => 'dejavusans',
    'ka' => 'dejavusans',
    'he' => 'dejavusans',
    'lo' => 'dejavusans',
    'lv' => 'dejavusans',
    'tr' => 'dejavusans',
    'ko' => 'cid0kr',
    'zh' => 'cid0cs',
    'tw' => 'cid0cs',
    'th' => 'freeserif'
    );
```

Disabling (commenting) the `'en' => 'dejavusans',` line did indeed solve the problem.

It's a bit of a hack obviously, so if anyone has information as to why English is in that list (and not French), and if there is a better way of handling this issue, I'm all ears. :)

Comment: ***1/*** -- You have been asked by KenS in the very first comment to provide a sample PDF. You haven't done so, so you will not get any more precise answers, but more likely some speculative musings (if any at all). French, using a lot of accented characters typically uses a different set of characters than English does (no accents). Hence, sometime in the far past, a developer may have decided to not support French because he didn't know how to handle accented characters. -- (continued)

Comment: ***2/*** -- Possibly the font used for French now is some default font, and possibly it is not embedded into the PDF, and therefor the PDF viewer of the day will use some substitute font for the not-embedded one (different on each system you open the file on, and possibly different for each printer you print it on....)

Comment: Come on... KenS asked for a sample PDF in order to help determining which font was used in it. That question has now been answered by another mean (it's DejaVuSans). So uploading a sample PDF would do nothing to help understanding the reasoning behind this specific bit of PHP programming in the Prestashop code. Thanks for your thoughts on the topic though.

Comment: **(1)** It wasn't clear from the beginning that you ask about *"this specific bit of PHP programming. -- **(2)** You asked specifically about fonts used in the two PDFs. -- **(3)** There may still more behind the problem than you can realize (based on your *very* limited understanding of PDF and PDF software that you have so far). -- Anyway, I'm glad you found a hackish workaround for now. Maybe you'll look for a proper solution later. Then ask again, if you like.

Comment: Also, KenS asked some 17 hours ago about a PDF sample (which could easily be created without including sensitive information into it). Your "solution" came 2 hours ago...

Answer (score 1):

> *"By the way, if somebody is able to identify (with reasonable certainty) which font is used in English (see image above), please let me know"*

You can identify with (almost) absolute certainty which fonts are used in both types of PDF files ***yourself***. Just run this command:

```
pdffonts -f 1 -l 5 pdffile.pdf
```

(This shows you all fonts used from page 1 to page 5 of the PDF, in case you are not interested in the other pages...)

If you get a `no` for both columns, `emb` as well as `sub`, then the font is not embedded in the PDF, and your PDF viewer is free to use any suitable substitute font it deems appropriate.

`pdffonts` is available for Linux, Unix, Mac OSX and Windows.

Comment: Actually, it's even simpler than that: in Acrobat, you can just use the File > Properties menu item and go to the Fonts tab. I didn't know that. ^^

Comment: @s427: Actually, in ***my*** opinion, this is not easier. And it works only in Acrobat. And it works only on platforms where Acrobat is installed. And it doesn't give you the option to see the result on a page-by-page basis. And it doesn't tell you as many details about the fonts. And it contains also some *confusing* information. (Or do you ***really*** understand what it exactly means, if an entry in this list is headlined `Helvetica`, and then below says: *`Actual font: Arial`* ??)

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but the truth is that it took me 15 seconds, it gave me an information that I was able to use. I didn't have to search for, install, configure or learn anything. Seems really simpler to me. ;)

Comment: I do usually upvote useful answers, and I appreciate you taking the time to help me. Your advice actually put me on the path to finding the solution. Things were just a bit hectic at work this morning and I neglected upvoting your answer.